# Showing that $A$ irreducible $\Leftrightarrow \bar{A}$ irreducible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> Let $A$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$.
>
> Show that $A$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $\bar{A}$ is irreducible.

My attempt:

$\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $A$ is reducible.

Then, there exist $A_1,A_2 \subseteq A$ closed and non-empty such that $A=A_1 \cup A_2$.

As $A_1$ and $A_2$ are closed, $\bar{A_1}=A_1$ and $\bar{A_2}=A_2$.

Thus, $\bar{A}=\overline{A_1 \cup A_2}=\bar{A_1} \cup \bar{A_2} = A_1 \cup A_2$.

As $A_1,A_2 \subseteq A \subseteq \bar{A}$ and $A_1,A_2$ are non-empty and closed, it follows that $\bar{A}$ is irreducible.

$\Rightarrow$) Is where I am stuck

I tried supposing that $\bar{A}$ is reducible.

Then, there exist $C_1,C_2 \subseteq \bar{A}$ closed and non-empty such that $\bar{A} =C_1 \cup C_2$.

But I can't go further...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The sets $C_1\cap A$ and $C_2\cap A$ will witness reducibility of $A$, provided that they are both non-empty, so you should try to prove that they’re non-empty. Suppose that $C_1\cap A=\varnothing$. $C_1\cup C_2=\operatorname{cl}A$, so $C_2\supseteq A$. And $C_2$ is closed, so ... ?

Comment: And are $C_1 \cap A$ and $C_2 \cap A$ closed and proper subsets of $A$?

Comment: @Leafar: They are certainly closed subsets of $A$. The hint suggests how to show that they are non-empty, proper subsets of $A$.

Comment: I understand why $A \subseteq C_2$, but what's next it is unclear... if $A \subseteq B$, then $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{B}$?

Comment: @Leafar: Yes, exactly — so $C_2$ isn’t a proper subset of $\operatorname{cl}A$.

Comment: I didn't found this property and it is not obvious for me, but I'll try to prove it later as a lemma

Comment: @Leafar: It’s very easy to prove that if $A\subseteq B$, then $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B$; it’s one of the basic facts about the closure operator. If you have any trouble proving it, leave a question here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have proved that $C_1 \cap A$ and $C_2 \cap A$ are proper subsets of $A$ following the ideia of the hint, but I don't see how to prove hat they are closed

Comment: @Leafar: That’s automatic: they’re the intersections with $A$ of closed sets, so by definition they’re relatively closed in $A$. They don’t have to be closed in $X$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot what we had to prove =D Now the last thing to see is that $A = (C_1 \cap A) \cup (C_2 \cap A)$. I'm going to try... $\supseteq$ is trivial

Comment: And $\subseteq$ follows from $A \subseteq \bar{A}$

Comment: @Leafar: Yep; you’ve got it.

Comment: Do you know some way to prove that $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow \bar{A} \subseteq \bar{B}$ without using neighborhoods?

Comment: @Leafar: It depends on how you’ve defined the closure. If you’ve defined $\operatorname{cl}A$ to be the set of points whose open nbhds all hit $A$, then using nbhds is the natural thing to do. If you’ve defined it as the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$, then the result is trivial: $\operatorname{cl}B$ is a closed set containing $A$, so $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B$. At some point you ought to prove that the two definitions are equivalent, so that you can use whichever is more convenient in any given problem.

Comment: The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ that contains $A$

Comment: @Leafar: If you know that, then you don’t need to argue using nbhds. You have $A\subseteq B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B$, so $\operatorname{cl}B$ is a closed set containing $A$; $\operatorname{cl}A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, so it must be the case that $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B$.

Comment: Ok, I think that's all, thanks for helping and thanks for the patience

Comment: @Leafar: You’re welcome.